# Let $A(z_{1})$ and $B(z_{2})$ be the roots of the equation $z^2+8(i-1)z+63-16i=0$ Find area of $\triangle OAB$.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $A(z_{1})$ and $B(z_{2})$ be the roots of the equation $$z^2+8(i-1)z+63-16i=0$$
Find area of $\triangle OAB$.(where $O\equiv (0,0)$)

**My Attempt:**

Using the quadratic formula$$z=\frac{8(1-i)\pm \sqrt{64(i-1)^2-4(63-16i)}}{2}=3+4i,5-12i$$

Area of triangle formed by joining the points $O(0,0)$,$A(3,4)$,$B(5,-12)$ is easily calculated to be $28$.

But I wonder if there is some neater method **without** having to calculate the roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the roots of $z^2 - a z + b=0$ be $\{r_1,r_2\}$.  The sum of the roots is $r_1+r_2=a$ and the product of the roots is $r_1r_2=b.$  The area of the triangle is $A=\frac{1}{2} \text{Im} \{r_1 \overline{r_2}\}$.  Don't see, at the moment, any quick way to get this.